# Need suggestions to optimize streamlit app - parsing output from grep results of a 15GB file

Tags: bash, grep, streamlit

I have made a small applet in Streamlit. The tool essentially greps a file and parses the resulting matches into two tables.

The parsing part works quite well, what I want to optimize is the grep / searching part.

The 20 GB file is a tab-seperated text file with the following structure, essentially variant information -

| Chr | Start | End | Ref | Alt | Gene | Het | Hom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 100 | 100 | A | T | A | abc | dfx |
| chr2 | 866 | 866 | C | A | B | jyh | bnf |

The input query for the streamlit app would be - `chr1\t100\t100\tA\tT`, i.e. column 1 to 5 copied and pasted into the search filed. We are using a `grep` command to find the information we need that is present in column `Het` and `Hom`.

The grep usually works well, taking around 5-9 seconds to parse the results. However, when the server is busy, the grep slows down quite a lot.

I want to try if there is a better way to make the query. The file has 3,212,304 lines, so I'm not sure if an SQL database would be optimal for the querying, or am I wrong?

Is there any tool / framework I can use to optimize the process? Any pointers are welcome!

EDITS - Few clarifications on my situation.

The number of queries per day can range anywhere from 0 up to 30. No/minimal activity on weekends. The file itself is updated once a month or so. Right now, we are updating the entire file.

In a way, I do want to listen to opinions and test out few things to optimize. We only have one server right now, so I just want to make the best of it.

Comment: This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: grep is quite optimized for an exact search like that. If server is busy... find another server. You can use databases, but you will lose more time introducing data and then extracting it in an already empty server, but if you use the same busy server as initially, then you will be in a worst situation.
Your problem is the server, not the algorithm.

Comment: I'm assuming you're running a lot of `grep` calls against this file; please update the question with more details on the bigger picture; if you're using `grep` as a method to routinely run queries against the 20GB file, yes, you may want to consider a database solution (or at a minimum, some sort of pre-indexed data solution); there's nothing 'efficient' in rescanning a 20GB file over and over and over ... all ... day .... long; some sort of pre-indexed data set will incur a cost for setup but lookups are going to be a lot faster and more efficient (vs repeated scans of a 20GB file)

Comment: also, a database (or pre-indexed data) solution will also need to consider updates (eg, are you routinely updating the 20GB file with inserts, deletes and/or updates?)

Comment: You don't even show a typical `grep` command. How you anchor patterns can make a considerable difference. If the data only changes once a month, you could consider spending some time just after it changes to pre-sort, or pre-filter, or pre-index your data.

Comment: If you are always searching on the last two fields, it might be fun to re-order the fields so the last two are first on each line and then time your searches. Or if there are only a limited number of possible values of one field, to split the file so that all the `dfx` values are in one and all the `bnf` fields are in another.

Comment: If your server is i/o bound, it may make sense to compress your data and use `zgrep`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `-F` and, if only 1 line can match, `-m 1` to improve the `grep` efficiency:

```
qry='chr1\t100\t100\tA\tT'
grep -F -m1 "${qry}\t" file
```

If you want to output the values from 2 columns and/or need the search to match at the start of the line to avoid false matches then use awk instead of grep:

```
qry='chr1\t100\t100\tA\tT'
awk -v qry="${qry}\t" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} index($0,qry)==1{print $7, $8; exit}' file
```

Remove the `; exit` if multiple lines can match.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. ```-m 1``` does appear to be a decent optimization, unless of course we are searching for entries in the end of file. We are looking for a robust solution, but that will come eventually!